# How can I fix glitchy Collision on my 2D game?

Tags: java, collision-detection

Update: I fixed the Negative axis glitch but the Invisible wall glitch still exists

I have made a 2D game in Java and I rewrote collision as I added chunks.
I have been having problems with the collision detection function, in the negative x-axis coordinates you fall through the world, and in the positive X-axis you sometimes hit into an invisible wall when there are no blocks next to you in that position.

I have tried altering all the numbers until it worked but the problems still happen

Here is the collision function (True = Yes, they are colliding with a Block | False = They are not colliding):

```java
public boolean isCollidingWithBlock(final Point2D.Double pt1, final Point2D.Double pt2) {
        for(int i=0;i<Level.Chunks.size();i++) {
            if (Math.floor((x)/(Level.chunkX*Tile.tileSize)) == Level.Chunks.get(i).chunkNumber) {
                int chunkN = Level.Chunks.get(i).chunkNumber;
                Point2D.Double chunkpoint = pt1;
                if (chunkpoint.x >= 0) {
                    chunkpoint.x = chunkpoint.x%(Level.chunkX*Tile.tileSize);
                } else {
                    chunkpoint.x = (chunkpoint.x%(Level.chunkX*Tile.tileSize))+((Level.chunkX*Tile.tileSize)*1);
                }
                Point2D.Double chunkpoint2 = pt2;
                if (chunkpoint2.x >= 0) {
                    chunkpoint2.x = chunkpoint2.x%(Level.chunkX*Tile.tileSize);
                } else {
                    chunkpoint2.x = (chunkpoint2.x%(Level.chunkX*Tile.tileSize))+((Level.chunkX*Tile.tileSize)*1);
                }               
                
                for (int x = (int)((this.x) / Tile.tileSize); x < (int)((this.x) / Tile.tileSize + 3.0); ++x) {
                    for (int y = (int)(this.y / Tile.tileSize); y < (int)(this.y / Tile.tileSize + 3.0); ++y) {
                        int chunkXPos = 0;
                        if (x >= 0) {
                            chunkXPos = (x%(Level.chunkX));
                        } else {
                            chunkXPos = (x%(Level.chunkX))+((Level.chunkX)*1);
                        }
                        if (chunkXPos >= 0 && y >= 0 && chunkXPos < Level.Chunks.get(i).blockData.length && y < Level.Chunks.get(i).blockData[0].length && Level.Chunks.get(i).blockData[chunkXPos][y].id != Tile.air && Level.Chunks.get(i).blockData[chunkXPos][y].id != Tile.water && (Level.Chunks.get(i).blockData[chunkXPos][y].contains(chunkpoint) || Level.Chunks.get(i).blockData[chunkXPos][y].contains(chunkpoint2))) {
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```